# Service stops when main app si closed

Tags: android, service, android-studio-2.3

When I close main app servic stops broadcasting intents. Where is mistake? I can't find any way to keep it running.

Broadcast recevier:

```
public class CustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Custom Broadcast recevied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

Service (AAA.java):

```
public class AAA extends Service {
final class MyThreadClass implements Runnable {
    int service_id;
    MyThreadClass(int service_id) {
        this.service_id = service_id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);

                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setAction("cz.johnyapps.custombroadcast");
                    sendBroadcast(i);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new MyThreadClass(startId));
    thread.start();

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}}
```

Manifest:

```
<service android:name="cz.johnyapps.notificationservice.AAA"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":ServiceProcess"/>
```

Main activity: startService(new Intent(this, AAA.class));

Answer (score 0):

Use `startForeground` method inside the Service to prevent such behavior

Comment: When the notification is displayed it works. But I need it without notification

Comment: You have to use foreground process to be sure your process will not be killed.

Comment: @HonzaJohnyPejsar bytheway , you can try Start_sticky flag

Comment: START_STICKY is not working and is used in code I've posted.

Comment: @HonzaJohnyPejsar, ok. the only solution is to use foreground process. So, no way to avoid this in common case.

Comment: So how does it for eg. YouTube doing? When there is new video it displays notification. There must be something running in background looking for new videos

Comment: @HonzaJohnyPejsar i do not really know your task. To do somethink in background (task for several seconds) you can use `wakefulbroadcastreceiver` class. It help the service to live for a while.

Comment: @HonzaJohnyPejsar , to wakeup a broadcast receiver you have to use alarm manager.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge one way is to make service running even after closing the app.

> You have to make as notification in you app which will bind the
>   service to it. if the app is closed that notification will be attached
>   which will be binding the service to it.

Example: Android phone default Media sound playing app, if you close the app an notification is shown on the notification bar which maintains the service to keep the music playing in the service.

Comment: I need it without notification

Comment: then you have to add a thread with will be running the all the time make that service alive.

Comment: how can I do it?

Comment: I think I've done it by Thread thread = new Thread(new MyThreadClass(startId));

Comment: Is it running the Service as you wanted ..?

Comment: Nope. It dies when I close main app